# How to run magento using port?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to run my magento in my local system like localhost:8080 instead of localhost/magento.

How to access magento using localhost:portnumber ?

Comment: I don't think that this is a magento related question

Comment: have you tried to set base url?

Comment: yes, i have tried in core_Config_data table